# React JS cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to get data from api, and set it in a state, and use it in map to iterate

```
    const result = await API.getSearch(data);

    if(result.status === 200){
        this.setState({data: result.data, loading: false })
    }

    const result = await API.getSearch(data); // got data successfully
```

Then:

```
this.state.data && this.state.data.length > 0 && this.state.data.data.map(function(value, i){
```

I know this kind of error mean, map didn't get any data, So I used condition, first I check if state return data, then check if data has length, but still get this error. any solution ?

Comment: You are checking `this.state.data` but you're using `this.state.data.data.map`

Comment: there is one `.data` too much

Comment: @Titus no no no! this.state.data , this is state name, and when data returned, there is a object /array called `data`

Comment: @messerbill read above comment

Comment: si si si! `this.state.data.data.map` there is one `.data` too much ;)

Comment: @tourtravel,  Can you share what are contents of `this.state.data`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look like you haven't initialized `data`.
So,**During the first rendering, it is `undefined`.**
On `undefined`,`map` is not exists.Causing this issue.

Declare and define `data` like this below

```
this.state = {
    data: []
}
```

OR

```
constructor(props) {
    this.state = {
        data: []
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess instead of this

```
this.state.data.data.map(function(value, i){
```

It should be only one time data

```
this.state.data.map(function(value, i){
```

Comment: no no no, api return json data, there is array called `data`

Answer (score 0):

Use destructure to have default values and make sure the inner `data` is array

```js
    const { data : { data = [] } = {} } = { data: { data: ['foo', 'bar']}  } ;
    
    console.log(data.map(x => x + "--").join());
```